# Convert/cast an address to uint256

Tags: solidity, addresses, bytes, type-casting, arbitrum

Following these details on the values that make part of the calldata that goes into an L2 message in Arbitrum:

[image]

https://developer.offchainlabs.com/docs/arbos_formats#l2-messages

How do you convert/cast an `address` to an `uint256`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

uint256(uint160(xAddr))

Comment: Maybe you can suggest a solution for converting vise versa using Web3.js?

Comment: No idea :/ @BeerBrother